# Line feeds in Eclipse layout XML

Tags: xml, eclipse

When the new project wizard creates a skeleton layout, the XML is nicely formatted with linefeeds for easy review.  But when I use the graphical layout form of the layout editor and drag an object into the layout, the resulting XML is all on one line.  How can I get the Eclipse graphical layout editor to insert linefeeds? I know I can do it manually, but that gets old real fast.  I have tried all the reasonable options in Windows > Preferences > XML > Editor.

Answer (score 0):

The preference is in preferences > Android > Editors, and selecting "Automatically format the XML edited by the visual layout editor" will format according to the XML editor preferences that you have set in XML > Editor.